# Is there a convenient way to clear the console while using artisan tinker?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'd like to be able to clear the console while using artisan tinker much like the way you would use **.cls** to clear the console while using sqlite3

Os: Windows
CLI: Git Bash / Powershell

Comment: Not familiar with your environment, but Ctrl + L works in Linux so it's worth a shot. :)

Comment: Thanks @JoelHinz I also use Linux and this might help but I use Windows majority of the time so I'll still need a fix for this since Ctrl + L did not work.

Answer (score 7):

I use iTerm2 and all you need to do is type:

```
clear
```

and it clears the console screen

Comment: I use Windows and Linux so this won't work for me. Any other tips?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-exit-the-tinker-console

Comment: @HamelRaj that link is for exiting tinker, not for clearing the console screen

Comment: Also, if you have text already written and want to clear that: Ctrl + w (which clears 1 word at a time).

Answer (score 3):

As of 6th July, 21 it does work on the windows console

```
clear // just type this
```

I'm on Windows Terminal using the default Command line and it does work.

Answer (score 0):

i use **ubuntu** and i press CTRL + L to clean console. whether it is tinker or not

Comment: OP knows about this. Their question is specifically about **Windows**. Please look at the tag. Also there's another hint in the comments under the question.

Comment: @EricAya i answered this question because in any answers it is not mentioned that Ctrl + L works while working in tinker. also i did see **windows** there. so i mentioned in my answer that i use **ubuntu**.